# PHP validate URL without http:// ot https:// or www. or subdomains

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in PHP to validate given URLS without http:// or https://  or subdomains just the domain name and MUST stat with (www.). Valid examples are:

```
    www.google.co.uk
    www.eample.tv
    www.example.com
    www.google.com
    www.dev.google.com
```

etc. Invalid examples are:

```
    wwww.eample.com/test
    wwww.example.com?exam
    http://wwww.google.com
    http://google.com
    ftp://www.google.com
    http://www.google.com/test/?test
    https://dev.example.com/test
    dev.example.com ( sub domains that doesnt start with www. are invalid)
```

etc. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I found this one ^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$  but it makes subdomains valid

Comment: Do you want this? https://regex101.com/r/nBEkHv/1

Comment: close I dont want it to match any sub domains or starting with www. or any sub domains , like this dev.example.com is not valid or www.example.com not valid

Comment: Do you want this? https://regex101.com/r/gNXQOX/1

Comment: Refer to https://regex101.com/r/tZH6sp/1 Good luck!

Comment: www is also a subdomain. That being said, based on your requirement it sounds like `/^www\./` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
^www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/iWSrPD/4

Comment: can I do it in preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/" , $m) ?

Comment: well in general if you write a regex that matches `google.co.uk` that will also match `dev.example.com`, cause pattern wise they are the same. If you can provide us with some more matching conditions (eg, minimum length of your domain name, list of domain type you want to validate etc) we can come up with something that works for you

Comment: can i add a codition where it must start with www. so these would be valid

Answer (score 0):

`/^[w]{3}\.[A-z0-9\-]+\.[A-z0-9\.]+$/i`

Comment: Add a bit of info / link to doc / explanation next time (like regex101.com )

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `/^www(?:\.[-\w]+)+$/` (`www` followed at least once by a dot followed by dash or word characters) matches all your *Valid examples* and doesn't match all your *Invalid examples*.

```
<?php
$examples = array
(   "www.google.co.uk", "www.eample.tv", "www.example.com", "www.google.com",
    "www.dev.google.com",
// Invalid examples are:
    "wwww.eample.com/test", "wwww.example.com?exam", "http://wwww.google.com",
    "http://google.com", "ftp://www.google.com",
    "http://www.google.com/test/?test", "https://dev.example.com/test",
    "dev.example.com",
);

foreach ($examples as $e)
{
    echo "$e is ";
    if (!preg_match('/^www(?:\.[-\w]+)+$/', $e)) echo "in";
    echo "valid\n";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this regex :

[`^(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$`](https://regex101.com/r/Nw9BBd/1)

Comment: does this end with " ` "?